# Ubuntu Bluetooth driver for Alienware Aurora R11

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, alienware

I recently dual booted with Windows and Ubuntu 20.04. My bluetooth is not working after trying a lot. The following is the list of results I get

```
lspi -knn | grep Net -A3
```

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac
Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)   Subsystem: Dell
QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:1810]   Kernel driver
in use: ath10k_pci  Kernel modules: ath10k_pci, wl

```
lsusb
```

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:0810 Microsoft Corp. LifeCam HD-3000

Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp.

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp.

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 187c:0550 Alienware Corporation AW-ELC

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

```
rfkill list
```

0: phy0: Wireless LAN

```
Soft blocked: no

Hard blocked: no
```

I have installed blueman manager and tried a bunch of things to make it work. the secure boot is disabled on UEFI.

Anyone has an idea on how to solve this? It would be really helpful

Update:

```
sudo lshw
```

Does not show bluetooth

Comment: What exactly did you try? What commands what results?

Comment: I do not see any Bluetooth hardware listed. Try `sudo lshw` and edit your question to show us the section specifically detailing your Bluetooth hardware.

Comment: @user535733 I have updated the post